# Cannot reach webpage for certificate generation on my developer account

Tags: icloud, apple-id, development, certificate

I am trying to reach the webpage for certificates under `developer.apple.com`. But I get redirected to the Welcome page. My Apple ID is an iCloud address `*...@icloud.com`.

---

Why does `https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/certificate/`
 redirect `to https://developer.apple.com/account/#/welcome` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your AppleID appears to not be registered as a Developer.  You must enroll in the Developer program to operate on certificates.